# Как завершить цикл for, находящийся в другой функции с помощью другой функции?

Tags: javascript, jquery

У меня возникла проблема.
Есть функция, по нажатию на которую, у меня запускается специальная анимация. Кроме css анимации у меня еще меняется текст через определенное время.
Вся функция длится 19 секунд: 4с - надпись inhale, 7с - надпись hold и 8с - надпись Exhale.

Когда я останавливаю функцию и через пару сек начинаю ее заного, то эта функция с циклами продолжает работать и сл-но не в нужное время меняет текст.

В коде ниже есть коменты.

```
$('#fall-asleep-btn').click(function fallAsleep(){
    // Vars for script. Эти переменные я получаю из одной библиотеки (Swiper)
    // В специальном окне человек выбирает сколько будет выполняться анимация

    var currentElement = mySwiper.activeIndex; //Время от 1м - 15м

    var newCurrentElement = currentElement * 3; // Count of itterations // за каждую минуту функция выпонится 3 раза

    var timeNewCurremtElement = newCurrentElement * 19000; // Всего функция занимает 19 сек.

    // Скрываю кнопку для старта и меню выбора времени
    $('.cube-content').hide();
    $('.fall-asleep-btn').css({
        'display' : 'none'
    });

    // Показываю кнопку для остановки
    $('.close-fall-asleep-btn').css({
        'display' : 'block'
    });

    // Главная функция
    function breathing_sleep() {
        // Start animation
        $('#in-hold-out').css({
            'display' : 'block',
            'animation-name' : 'inHOLDout',
            'animation-duration' : '19s',
            'animation-iteration-count' : newCurrentElement,
            'animation-fill-mode' : 'ease-in-out'
        });

    // Тут и есть проблема. Когда я останавливаю функцию и через пару сек начинаю ее заного, то эта функция с циклами продолжает работать и сл-но не в нужное время меняет текст.

        function TextChanger() {

            // 1 Period
            for (var m = 0; m <= timeNewCurremtElement; m=m+19000) {
                var period_1 = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#in-hold-out').html("Inhale");
                }, m);
            }

            // 2 Period
            for (var i = 4000; i <= timeNewCurremtElement; i=i+19000) {
                var period_2 = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#in-hold-out').html("Hold");
                }, i);
            }

            // 3 Period
            for (var j = 11000; j <= timeNewCurremtElement; j=j+19000) {
                var peropd_3 = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#in-hold-out').html("Exhale");
                }, j);
            }

            // 4 Period
            for (var k = 19000; k <= timeNewCurremtElement; k=k+19000) {
                var period_4 = setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#in-hold-out').html("Inhale");
                }, k);
            }

        }

        TextChanger();

        // Анимация с поздравлениями об окончание всего процесса
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#in-hold-out').hide();

            $('#WellDone-night').css({
                'display' : 'block',
                'animation-name' : 'WellDone',
                'animation-duration' : '4s',
                'animation-`введите сюда код`iteration-count' : 1,
                'animation-fill-mode' : 'ease-in-out'
            });
        }, timeNewCurremtElement);      
    }

    // После поздравлений появляется первоночальное меню выбора времени
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#WellDone-night').hide();
        $('.cube-content').fadeIn(1000);

        // Show start button
        $('.fall-asleep-btn').css({
            'display' : 'block'
        });

        // Hide stop button
        $('.close-fall-asleep-btn').css({
            'display' : 'none'
        });
    }, timeNewCurremtElement + 4000);

    // Stop animation at all
    function non_breath_sleep() {
        $('#in-hold-out').css({
            'animation' : ''
        });
    }

    // Start main func. + Start func. to stop animation
    breathing_sleep();
    setTimeout(non_breath_sleep, timeNewCurremtElement);

    return 0;
});
```

И вот функция для завершения процесса. Тут я не знаю как остановить ту функцию(TextChanger) со сменой текста.

```
$('.close-fall-asleep-btn').click(function() {

    // Func. to end animation
    function non_breath_sleep() {
        $('#in-hold-out').css({
                'animation-play-state' : 'stop'
        });
    }

    non_breath_sleep();

    // Show main content
    $('.cube-content').fadeIn(1000);

    // Hide animation text
    $('#in-hold-out').hide();

    // Show start button
    $('.fall-asleep-btn').css({
        'display' : 'block'
    });

    // Hide stop button
    $('.close-fall-asleep-btn').css({
        'display' : 'none'
    });

    return 0;
});
```

Я мучаюсь с этим уже порядка нескольких дней, но до сих пор не могу найте ответ. Если Вы мне сможете помочь, то я буду Вам безмерно благодарен! Спасибо заранее!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ту функцию (`TextChanger`)  Вы не сможете остановить, потому что она уже давно отработала. Вы в ней в трех циклах насоздавали таймеров, ссылки на которые нигде не сохранены, и которые будут выстреливать в заказанное время. И ничего Вы с этим не сделаете.

Уберите все Ваши `setTimeout`-ы и оставьте один `setInterval`, результат которого сохраните в переменной. Всю логику, определяющую какой текст показывать, поместите в обработчик интервала. Тогда Вы сможете "остановить" Вашу функцию, вызвав `clearInterval`.

Заведите счетчик для отсчета секунд. Логика кода в обработчике интервала будет зависеть от этого счетчика. Не забудьте очищать счетчик, когда останавливаете интервал.

```js
var counter = 0;
var timer;

function TextChanger() {
  counter = 0;
  clearInterval(timer);

  timer = setInterval(function() {
    counter++;
    if (counter <= 4) {
      $('#in-hold-out').html("Text 1");
    } else if (counter <= 11) {
      $('#in-hold-out').html("Text 2");
    } else if (counter <= 19) {
      $('#in-hold-out').html("Text 3");
    } else {
      counter = 0;
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Окей, но я не понимаю как мне 4 действия, которые должны происходить в разное время, запихнуть в 1 Interval

Comment: @slower. Заведите счетчик для отсчета секунд. Логика кода в обработчике интервала будет зависеть от этого счетчика. Не забудьте очищать счетчик, когда останавливаете интервал.

Comment: Можете написать пример счетчика и как interval будет зависеть от него? Я, как начинающий, ума не приложу как это реальзовать
Спасибо

Comment: Это похоже на счетчик, о котором Вы говорите?

var sec_counter;

function sec_counter(){
 for(i = 1000; i <= timeNewCurremtElement; i = i + 1000){
  console.log(i);
        }
}

Comment: @slower. Это что? Нет, непохоже.

Comment: Это счетчик. Возможно я не прав

Comment: Но можете тогда показать, если Вас это не сильно затруднит

Comment: @slower. Я уже добавил код в ответ.

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромное, извините, что так часто отвлекал Вас

Comment: @slower. На здоровье. Успехов!